# Detect error from clean_fieldname in django template

Tags: django

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   ....

    def clean_myfield(self):
        ....
        ....
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wow error!")
        return myfield
```

How can I add "if statment" in Django Template if this error(from clean_myfield) exist?

```
{% if error_from_clean_myfield %}
   ...... 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the variable:

```
{{ form.myfield.errors }}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template).

Comment: I meant error from `clean_myfield`. Not all errors.

Comment: You haven't read the documentation thoroughly. Django creates a list of errors for each field.  You can loop over that list if you need to.

Comment: I can: `{% for error in form.myfield.errors %}{% if error == "Error from clean" %} ... ` but this is hardcode error message.

Comment: Yes, I can't think of any other method. After all it is a pretty strange pattern. Why would you do something so special with this error other then displaying it?